# UnityEditor increasing font size

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts, scripting

I'm starting to play with UnityEditor, surely a good idea !

The trick is that the UI font sizes are deseperately too small for my eyes, so I need to play with desktop zoom... hmm, this is boring in fact !

Is there a scripting / skining or theming way to increase slightly font sizes of the Unity Editor UI

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Still under review, over 5000 votes though, so you are not alone!

It's going back to 2011 when first reported.

[CHANGE FONT SIZE IN UNITY EDITOR](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/change-font-size-in-unity-editor?page=1#comments)

[how-to-change-font-size-in-the-editor.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-change-font-size-in-the-editor.373423/)

[changing-font-size-in-gui.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/changing-font-size-in-gui.13158/)

If you're on Windows, you could always use this:

[image]

Comment: Ughh ! do you really use it ? the same in Xubuntu ... It makes me sick... since screen follows the mouse pointer... I guessed that  25+ lines of code could do the job...

Comment: I’ve been using Unity to build games off and on since 2011, since version 3. I too am surprised that over 2-3 major versions they haven’t addressed this, but it’s a massively popular engine and so they probably have a gigantic load of features and this just hasn’t hit the PMs radar.

Comment: @Hefeust did I sufficiently answer your question? Can I help in more ways?

Comment: if I could just know about the global CSharp variablz holoding the editor instance, probably I will do this script !

Comment: @Hefeust sorry I do not know how to help you with that. If I need to adjust my answer let me know.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Didn't expect Windows to have such a nice feature...

Answer (score 5):

You can change the Unity's Editor UI Scaling independent of Windows (or ths OS u use...)Scale:

1. Go to **Edit/Preferences/UI Scaling**.
   2.On UI Scaling options disable or **uncheck the option "Use default desktop setting"**, this enable the dropdown list option called **"Use custom scaling value"**.
2. Finally, **select the percentage scale from the options in the dropdown you want to set** for you Unity UI...
3. Enjoy bigger Unity UI...

[Screenshot about the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUUDg.png)

Comment: There is no such option under macOS.

Comment: No such option exists under Ubuntu either...

Comment: It works fine on Windows, Unity 2022.3.11f1. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to change your fontsize programatically I am not sure but I hope this might help you or gives you some idea to solve , I am attaching the link for reference https://gist.github.com/nukadelic/47474c7e5d4ee5909462e3b900f4cb82

```
    {
        if( ! RESIZE_ON_LAUNCH || DEFAULT_GLOBAL_FONT_SIZE <= 10 ) return;
        var w = GetWindow<EditorFontSize>();
        w.GUICallback = () => {
            w.Resize( DEFAULT_GLOBAL_FONT_SIZE - 10 ) ;
            w.Close();
        };
    }
```